# How to automatically store only Logon event information from Security log over a long period of time?

Tags: event-log

I have a Windows server that is used by a large number of people and we are looking to upgrade it and move everyone to a new server.

I would like to identify the current users in order to notify them in advance.

I have enabled logon auditing and can see Event ID 4624 in the current Security log, along with the user IDs.  So far so good.

But the Security log fills up very quickly!  At a configured size of 200 MB, it lasts only a day before the content is archived.

It is possibly to have Windows save the 4624 event, **and only that event** somewhere automatically, so that I can have a record of all the future logons for a period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can do that by writing a custom application/service for that. You can use both EventLog class and EventLogWatcher class for achieving it.

> Main Logic:

```
string queryString = "<QueryList><Query Id=\"0\" Path=\"Security\">"
                    +"<Select Path=\"Security\">*[System[(EventID=4624)]]</Select>"
                    +"</Query></QueryList>";
EventLogWatcher watcher = new EventLogWatcher(new EventLogQuery("Security", PathType.LogName,queryString));
watcher.EventRecordWritten += new EventHandler<EventRecordWrittenEventArgs>(EventGenerated);
watcher.Enabled = true;
```

> EventHandler:

```
public void EventGenerated(object source, EventRecordWrittenEventArgs args){
    //Do whatever you want here
}
```